# dynamic configuration of the tomcat-users.xml file

Tags: jsp, tomcat, configuration

I have an oracle database, and I am creating a web interface for it. I am making a servlet for login, where it asks for a user name and password, after which a user can access the web interface. If a user does not have an account, I have a link to a page where they can register. In terms of where the username and password are created, ideally I would like to create it in oracle (I can do this using jdbc), but I would also like to dynamically update the tomcat-users.xml file to reflect this update (the same username/password), along with the users role. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Why? Devastatingly insecure, and pointless. What's the objective?

Comment: the idea is that i would eventually also like to include an email server, and potentially a file server. In essence, I'd like the user to be able to log in once and have access to everything from one interface

Comment: also, thank you for your response. just curious as to what are the security risks to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to configure Tomcat to fetch your user data directly from the database. You could start by reading [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html) on authentication realms.

Comment: thx for ur response. so does this mean that i would basically ignore the tomcat login? if i was to add an email server in the future, would/should i store and fetch the login data from oracle as well?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic users and users role configuration, use [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

Comment: thx for ur response. with spring security, would i have to restart tomcat every time a user is created (i.e. the tomcat-users.xml file is updated with elevated priviledges)?